# Google Apps Email Settings API - Audit Log

Tags: google-apps

I'm using Email Settings API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/) to change a user signature.

The client wants it to be logged on Google Apps somehow. I checked google apps Audit Logs (https://admin.google.com/AdminHome#Reports/subtab=audits&subtabchild=cpanel) and it doesn't show the actions made by the API.

Is there anywhere else a screen with this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email Settings API changes are not logged in the Google Apps Control Panel Admin Audit Log. Your app can maintain it's own log of changes made but this functionality is not available directly.